# Изнутри контейнера нет связи, в то время как обращения к контейнеру работают

Tags: debian, виртуализация, lxc

Установил lxc контейнер, прописал для него все конфиги.

файл ***/etc/network/interfaces***

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
#auto  eth0
#iface eth0 inet static
#address   213.239.197.111
#netmask   255.255.255.224
#gateway   213.239.197.97
# default route to access subnet
#up route add -net 213.239.197.96 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 213.239.197.97 eth0

auto br0 
  iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_fd 0 
  address 213.239.197.111
  broadcast 213.239.197.127
  netmask 255.255.255.224
  gateway 213.239.197.97
  post-up /sbin/ip ro add 213.239.197.122/32 dev br0

# Создаем bridge br0

#    auto br0  
#    iface br0 inet static   
#    bridge_ports none 
#    bridge_fd 0 
#    address 10.0.0.1  
#    netmask 255.255.255.0 

iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2a01:4f8:130:622e::2
netmask 64
gateway fe80::1
```

конфигурация контейнера

```
# Template used to create this container: /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-download
# Parameters passed to the template:
# For additional config options, please look at lxc.container.conf(5)

# Distribution configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/ubuntu.common.conf
lxc.arch = x86_64

# Container specific configuration
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/crm/rootfs
lxc.utsname = crm

# Network configuration
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags        = up
lxc.network.name         = eth1
lxc.network.link         = br0
lxc.network.veth.pair    = veth-01
lxc.network.ipv4         = 213.239.197.122/28
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 213.239.197.97
lxc.network.hwaddr       = 00:50:56:00:9C:81
```

но сети нету на контейнере. куда хотя бы смотреть?

вывод команды ***systemctl status networking.service***

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
       └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-03-09 23:10:17 UTC; 5s ago
 Docs: man:interfaces(5)
Process: 192 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 189 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && u
devadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 192 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: Это не виртуалка, а контейнер, это разные вещи

Comment: извиняюсь, раньше хотел виртуалку настроить, теперь постоянно путаю

Comment: при чем, если делать ***ping*** с хост машины на контейнер - он проходит

Answer (score 1):

у вас какой-то разнобой в сетях.

в контейнере сеть: `213.239.197.112/28`. а умолчальным шлюзом назначен `213.239.197.97`, который в эту сеть **не входит** (как и адрес основной машины — `213.239.197.111`).

вероятно, у контейнера должна быть такая же сеть, как и у основной машины: `213.239.197.96/27`.

т.е., строка с назначением адреса должна выгледеть как:

```
lxc.network.ipv4         = 213.239.197.122/27
```

---

p.s. и эта строка в конфигурации основной машины — явно лишняя:

```
post-up /sbin/ip r a 213.239.197.122/32 dev br0
```

Comment: сделал как вы написали, не помогло. на контейнере запустил команду ***systemctl status networking.service*** и вот что она показала - добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Diefair, возможно, вы понимаете, что там написано. я, к сожалению, не понимаю даже, зачем вы привели вывод этой команды: это же у вас контейнер (для одной программы), а не виртуальная машина с полноценной инициализацией.